# Assigning to NSNumber from incompatible type double

Tags: ios, nsnumber, incompatibletypeerror

In a header file, I am declaring the following property:

```
//lat
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *lat;
```

Then in the implementation file I get a double variable from an array:

```
double lat1 = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitud"] doubleValue];
```

and then I want to assign this value to the previous declared lat instance:

```
annotation3.lat = lat1;
```

But doing this throws an error:

> Assigning to NSNumber from incompatible type double.

What should I change to do this without errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSNumber` literal syntax:

```
annotation3.lat = @( lat1 );
```

or create an instance the old fashioned way:

```
annotation3.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat1];
```

Also, be sure you just want your property to use `assign` (you usually want to use `strong`).